# Grub.cfg doesn't show any of my boot options

Tags: grub2, bootloader

Grub.cfg doesn't show any of my boot options

Have one partitioned HDD with Windows-7 32 bit and xUbuntu recently installed on a smaller partition of the same drive.

When booted the computer gives me a brief menu showing:
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
Mem test
mem test+
Windows 7 loader on /dev/sda1

However when I gedit /etc/grub/grub.cgf  there are no options or systems loaded just a timeout option of 10 and some comment lines.  Thus I think the REAL BOOTLOADER is elsewhere, but where & how do I configure it?

Also I think an update to Ubuntu failed as "some program was using the bootblock for data storage". That may have been a 3rd party windows bootloader editor which I deleted.

Comment: The file `/etc/grub/grub.cfg` does not exist in Ubuntu, not even the folder `/etc/grub`. Please clarify which file you really mean.

Comment: the grub configuration file

Answer (score 1):

**To edit the GRUB Configuration File :**

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

However I recommend to just fix grub if you can see the menu but don't see the boot options.

Use the following command in the terminal :

```
# update-grub
```

Comment: okay will do.  I'll edit this commment w/ results

Answer (score 1):

Grub has two configuration files:

```
/etc/default/grub 
/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

The file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` contains the menu-entries for the boot-menu, you should find all installed operating systems in this file. This file is created by scripts which reside in `/etc/grub.d/`. It is not recommended to edit this file manually as the file would be overwritten whenever you run `update-grub`. This would happen automatically when a new kernel gets installed during an upgrade. When Grub starts, Grub will read it's configuration and menu-entries from this file.

The file `/etc/default/grub` is the configuration file we can edit manually to adjust the behavior of Grub to our demands. The changes we make here are persistent. To edit this file root-privileges are needed.

To apply the changes we make in `/etc/default/grub` to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` we have to run `sudo update -grub`.Take a look at https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html#Simple-configuration to get an overview about the several options.

Comment: Thanks, now have it working on Ubuntu 18.0.4.  Thanks for your clear explanation.  I reinstalled the Windows to W10 64 bit {Advertizing Edition} and was able to get the the duel boot to work.